# Same Array in Different Procedures

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm really new to C, and currently I'm trying to read in from a file which contains a list of names, and import that into an array. The current array is of type char[][] since it will have more information than just the name, but essentially I want team[0][0] to be the first name i read in, team[1][0] to be the second, etc. I'm pretty sure the actual importing of the names is correct, but I'm having problems storing these arrays.

```
FILE *teamfile;
teamfile = fopen(file, "r");
char line[MAXLENGTH+1];
int i = 0;
while( fgets(line, sizeof line, teamfile) != NULL )
{
    trim_line(line);
    strcpy(&team[i][NAME],line);
    i++;        
}
fclose(teamfile);
```

Which is called from the main function as `teams = teamlist(argv[1], team);`
But when I try to refer to the array from elsewhere in my program eg `printf(&team[0][0])` it outputs what seems to be all names in one block...
What am I doing wrong?

edit:

```
static void trim_line(char line[])
{
    int i = 0;

//  LOOP UNTIL WE REACH THE END OF line
    while(line[i] != '\0')
    {

//  CHECK FOR CARRIAGE-RETURN OR NEWLINE
        if( line[i] == '\r' || line[i] == '\n' )
        {
            line[i] = '\0'; // overwrite with nul-byte
            break;          // leave the loop early
        }
        i = i+1;            // iterate through character array
    }
}
```

thanks for the help so far! :D

Answer (score 1):

if `team` is declared as `char team[NUM_OF_TEAMS][LENGHT_OF_NAME]`

then it should always be `strcpy(&team[i],line);`

Hint: it is a `char array,` not a "`string object`" in C